# Converting a MEF application to utilize Rx (System.Reactive)

Tags: c#, mef, system.reactive

So the current situation is I have a program that is completely utilizing MEF. Now I want to make it utilize Rx as to allow it to scale to larger queries and allow the user to look over results as the various plugins return results. It is currently setup as such:

**Workflow:** Query => DetermineTypes => QueryPlugins => Results

Currently the code is all stored on GitHub if anyone needs to reference more than what I post below.
[ALeRT on GitHub](https://github.com/thelordzero/ALeRT)

The VS solution has a UI project (default StartUp Project), a PluginFramework Project, various TypePlugin Projects (think determining what the type is such as a URL, Email, File, Phone Number, etc) and also QueryPlugin Projects (perform xyz if the queryplugin supports the type that has been determined). All the results are displayed back into the UI by ways of a DataGrid that is being mapped to by the DefaultView of a DataTable.

I want to try and make the Rx portion as invisible to the plugins as possible. This is due to the fact that I do not want to make writing plugins complex for the few people that will. So I was thinking about taking the current Framework below:

```
public interface IQueryPlugin
{
    string PluginCategory { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string Version { get; }
    string Author { get; }
    System.Collections.Generic.List<string> TypesAccepted { get; }
    string Result(string input, string type, bool sensitive);
}
```

and making the Result method into the following:

```
System.IObservable<string> Result(string input, string type, bool sensitive);
```

This would naturally require modifying the method that is calling the plugin which as it stands is:

```
                using (GenericParserAdapter parser = new GenericParserAdapter())
                {
                    using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(qPlugins.Result(query, qType, sensitive)))
                    {
                        Random rNum = new Random();

                        parser.SetDataSource(sr);
                        parser.ColumnDelimiter = Convert.ToChar(",");
                        parser.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
                        parser.MaxBufferSize = 4096;
                        parser.MaxRows = 500;
                        parser.TextQualifier = '\"';

                        DataTable tempTable = parser.GetDataTable();
                        tempTable.TableName = qPlugins.Name.ToString();
                        if (!tempTable.Columns.Contains("Query"))
                        {
                            DataColumn tColumn = new DataColumn("Query");
                            tempTable.Columns.Add(tColumn);
                            tColumn.SetOrdinal(0);
                        }

                        foreach (DataRow dr in tempTable.Rows)
                        {
                            dr["Query"] = query;
                        }

                        if (!resultDS.Tables.Contains(qPlugins.Name.ToString()))
                        {
                            resultDS.Tables.Add(tempTable);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            resultDS.Tables[qPlugins.Name.ToString()].Merge(tempTable);
                        }
                        pluginsLB.DataContext = resultDS.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Select(t => t.TableName).ToList();
                    }
                }
```

So at this point I'm stuck as to how to make this work. There doesn't seem to be good documentation on how to integrate MEF with Rx. My assumption is to make the following change

```
using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(qPlugins.Result(query, qType, sensitive).Subscribe()))
```

but this isn't going to work. So any help on making these changes would be greatly appreciated. If you have other suggestions regarding my code, please let me know. I do this as a hobby so I know my code surely isn't up to snuff for most people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you:

```
IObservable<DataTable> q =
    from text in qPlugins.Result(query, qType, sensitive)
    from tempTable in Observable.Using(
        () => new GenericParserAdapter(),
        parser => Observable.Using(
            () => new StringReader(text),
            sr => Observable .Start<DataTable>(
                () =>
                {
                    var rNum = new Random();

                    parser.SetDataSource(sr);
                    parser.ColumnDelimiter = Convert.ToChar(",");
                    parser.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
                    parser.MaxBufferSize = 4096;
                    parser.MaxRows = 500;
                    parser.TextQualifier = '\"';

                    var tempTable = parser.GetDataTable();
                    tempTable.TableName = qPlugins.Name.ToString();
                    if (!tempTable.Columns.Contains("Query"))
                    {
                        DataColumn tColumn = new DataColumn("Query");
                        tempTable.Columns.Add(tColumn);
                        tColumn.SetOrdinal(0);
                    }

                    foreach (DataRow dr in tempTable.Rows)
                        dr["Query"] = query;

                    return tempTable;
                })))
    select tempTable;
```

Comment: I'll have to take a look at it when I get home, though it does show a lot of promise. This should theoretically work fine with my {Binding} to change the DataGrid from a ComboBox correct?

        private void pluginsLB_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            resultsDG.ItemsSource = resultDS.Tables[pluginsLB.SelectedValue.ToString()].DefaultView;
        }

Comment: Ok so I tried it and I'm getting two problems with that code:
**Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.IObservable<string>'.  'SelectMany' not found.** is the error for this portion `from text in qPlugins.Result(query, qType, sensitive)` and also **Unreachable code detected** in `foreach (DataRow dr in tempTable.Rows)
dr["Query"] = query;` Any suggestions on how to fix those problems?

Comment: @lordzero - I think that the error you're getting might just be that you haven't got a `using System.Reactive.Linq` at the top of your code. I tested that the code compiled before I uploaded it. If you can fix this I think the other issue will go away.

Comment: @lordzero - I would look at how you are dealing with the `pluginsLB_SelectionChanged` event. You probably should recode with the observable `.FromEventPattern` and then combine this with the code in my answer. It is not a good idea to mix observable with non-observable code. Usually if you just use observables your code is tighter and easier to debug.

Comment: You were right. I had thought I had added the resource earlier and completely forgot I hadn't. I do have one last problem (I think and hope). As I said initially, I was looking at making the interface System.IObservable<string>. I guess I spoke to soon in assuming I knew how to implement it in the actual plugin. Would you be able to give me an example of how to take the string I was returning and return it correctly for the plugin loader. I'm apparently a bit daft in figuring out how to do so. :\

Comment: @lordzero - I don't understand what you're asking. Perhaps you need to post another question and give me the link to go look at it?

Comment: At your request, here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852418/making-mef-plugins-work-with-rx Thanks again for all your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: So I just noticed that with the change to Rx, you removed a bit of the functionality. The various DataTables are not being combined into a DataSet. That names of the DataTables in the DataSet are not being bound to ListBox and the DataGrid never gets bound to by what is being selected in the ListBox. Think you can take a second look?

Comment: Also if it is of benefit, I have uploaded the copy as it stands now to [ALeRT on GitHub](https://github.com/thelordzero/ALeRT).

Comment: @lordzero - I removed the code that did that because it wasn't compatible with Rx. You should not be building the `DataSet`. You should fetch the `DataTable` only when you need it.

Comment: @lordzero - Also you shouldn't have a `pluginsLB_SelectionChanged` event handler. Use Rx and the `.FromEventPattern` to create an observable from your selection changes and then use a `SelectMany` on the `Results` observable to get your `DataTable`. Subscribe to this and then populate your results.

Comment: @lordzero - I just downloaded the code from GitHub and it doesn't compile. I'm missing a reference for `GenericParsing`. Your code needs some significant refactoring which I can't do unless it compiles.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I don't think anyone else has downloaded it and so I've been forgetting to move the .dll into the solution. I've since moved it into the Pre-Compiled directory in ALeRT.UI. You should be able to redownload the whole thing again from GitHub if you like. If for some reason it fubars up, it was originally gotten from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F